# Can I remove wordpress inline css?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, inline

I have this problem :

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ITR/timthumb.php?src=http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/90-0331-e1336510507762.jpg&amp;w=940&amp;h=320&amp;zc=1" alt="" class="png preload" ;="" style="opacity: 0;" />
```

I want to change the `style="opacity: 0"` to `style="opacity: 100"`

How can I do that ? With jQuery ?

Comment: Please note that opacity is set with a value between 0 and 1

Comment: @michaelward82: You are correct, however wouldn't any value above 1 just be treated as 1 anyway?

Comment: The specification suggests that "Any values outside the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) will be clamped to this range." - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency - of course, this means you'd be relying on correct error handling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with jQuery:

```
$('.png.preload').css({'opacity':1});
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in a comment to the original question, opacity is a value between 0 and 1. I modified the jQuery snippet above to reflect that.

Comment: @downvoter: I assume the downvote was because of the previous error in the opacity value? My mistake - I overlooked that. Although, I believe if you set the opacity to anything above 1, it would essentially treat it as 1.

Comment: Thank you ! 
But where to input this jQuery snippet ?

Comment: @ErolMujak: You would put it between a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag. Also, be sure you're including the jQuery library, and wrap the snippet like this `$(function(){ /* snippet here */});`. You can read about the basics of jQuery [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

Better is Removing that attribute, you can use the jQuery `removeAttr` for it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.png.preload').removeAttr('style')
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the style attribute with jQuery

`jQuery("img.png.preload").attr('style', 'opacity: 1');`

Comment: Setting the attribute like this looks like poor form when you can set the css directly with .css({'opacity':1}, not affecting other styles applied.